# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 suspends after booting up

Tags: 16.04, gnome, suspend, laptop

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

When booting up it shows the logo and it goes into suspend.

How do I find the issue and fix it?

Comment: The laptop actually goes to sleep or are you getting a blank screen?

Comment: It goes to sleep, and it will wake when i press the power button

Answer (score 1):

I think I had almost the same issue after upgrading fom 14.04 on an older SAMSUNG laptop. Even booting from an install media (CD) did not work: The laptop went into suspend or hybernate mode every 10sec. 
After booting from an 14.04 install media I could change **HandleSuspendKey** and **HandleLidSwitch** to **ignore** in */etc/systemd/logind.conf*. This solved my problem. See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178047

Comment: Having the same issue under Linux 19.1. Editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as mentioned solved the issue.